# Graphical Wireless scanning

Tags: wireless, gui, intel-wireless

I am able to connect to a Wireless network using the graphical interface of Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity) by manually configuring a network whose name I know.

I can also scan for networks and their information using the terminal command `sudo iwlist scanning | less` and this works just fine. But there used to be a nice graphical way to look at available wireless networks, just by opening the drop-down menu in the upper right corner of the screen. Even when I *am* connected to a wireless network, I no longer see any networks (or signal strengths) in this drop-down menu. What could have happened? I am working on a Dell XPS 13 laptop, the Wifi is Intel Wireless 8260, the kernel version is 4.4.0.

**EDIT:** It would seem that this problem sometimes appears and disappears after rebooting or connecting/disconnecting with certain networks. JPS' solution provides a temporary workaround, but problem comes back once in a while. I will try to figure out what exactly triggers the problem, but sometimes it is just there when the computer boots up.

Comment: Check if nm-applet is up and running with `ps -e | grep nm-applet`, and if not, try launching it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the Network Manager by running in terminal:

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

Comment: Hi JPS. This solves the problem temporarily, but it might or not might not come back after a reboot of the system.

Comment: yes, i know and i get the same issue sometimes after suspend. it seems to be a bug.
my temporary workaround is a .desktop file with the command running in terminal.
Do you filed a bug on Launchpad against NetworkManager?

Comment: Not yet, I will once I am more certain when exactly the problem appears.